# div jumps when seting border

Tags: javascript, css

When a user cliks on a div (see attached screenshots bellow) I'm setting a border with:

```
$div.addClass("selected-block");
```

In CSS I have:

```
div.selected-block {
   border: 2px solid #155BCE !important; 
   border-radius:3px;
}
```

After the border is set `top` and `left` of text are increased on `3`. How is it possible to avoid this?

**PS.** I thought of making white border for deselected div, but it's not a good solution as white border can intersect black lines.

Comment: You forgot the screenshot, although a jsfiddle or similar would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the element with a 2px transparent border, and just change the bordercolor.

```
div {
   border: 2px solid transparent; 
   border-radius: 3px;}

div.selected-block {
   border-color: #155BCE; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have some padding (top and left 2px?) in the regular css. Set padding to 0px in selected-block so that the border width acts like padding substitute. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

**Used to** `css3 box-sizing` **properties**

Like this

```
div.selected-block{
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: the first rule on every page [`* { box-sizing: border-box }`](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) :)